# Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

hi can anyone help me with this im sitting with this error for like an hour now but cant figure out how to fix this error my code is

```
'Calculate the total of hours worked

'Declare a Date Time Variable   

    Dim TempDateTime As DateTime = Nothing
    'Declare a local time span variable
    Dim TempTimeSpan As New TimeSpan
    'Declare a array of type string and set the size equal to number of text boxes.
    Dim arr(6) As String
    'set the value for text boxs to array
    arr(0) = lblmontotal.Text
    arr(1) = lbltuestotal.Text
    arr(2) = lblwedtotal.Text
    arr(3) = lblthurstotal.Text
    arr(4) = lblfridtotal.Text

    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        TempDateTime = CDate(arr(i))
        TempTimeSpan = TempTimeSpan.Add(New TimeSpan(TempDateTime.Hour, TempDateTime.Minute, 0))
    Next
    'showing the total time.
    lbltotalhours.Text = (TempTimeSpan.Hours & ":" & TempTimeSpan.Minutes)
```

Comment: use `New DateTime(arr(i))`

Comment: thanks for a fast reply..let me try that one..

Comment: hey sorry for being a noob but i have another problem..after trying that code it return this error "Conversion from string "00:00:00" to type 'Long' is not valid."

Comment: my lblmontotal.text format is ("hh:mm:ss")

Comment: And what is the content of each label / array element? Seems like you are trying to "convert" an empty string to a Date, which is obviously invalid. Oh btw, `Dim TempDateTime As DateTime = Nothing` is quite useless. You know it will have the value `01/01/0001 00:00:00`?

And also one rule I try to uphold. I try to avoid to use anything in the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly. It only leads to dirty stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not assigned anything to array elements 5 and 6. When you hit those elements in the loop, `CDate` will return the error you have described.

Tip - instantiate your array like this instead. That way, the compiler will calculate the length for you and avoid bugs like this.

```
'set the value for text boxs to array
Dim arr As String() = {
    lblmontotal.Text,
    lbltuestotal.Text,
    lblwedtotal.Text,
    lblthurstotal.Text,
    lblfridtotal.Text
}
```

**UPDATE**

With regard to your second question, there are lots of ways of doing this, but the simplest is to convert the value directly to a `TimeSpan`, and don't bother with the `DateTime` variable at all.

Comment: yeah its all my fault guys..thanks for helping me fix the error its ok and running now..

Comment: im sorry for all the trouble..i just forgot to change that after deleting lblsattotal.text and lblsuntotal.text xD

Comment: 1000 upvotes to you. Furthermore, OP should use a `For Each` loop. Indexed for loops have become almost completely unnecessary.

Comment: I agree, just trying to do baby steps. Personally I would do the entire block of code in one LINQ expression. :-)

Comment: yeah im still a noob but trying to use a difficult code =)..but thanks i appreciate the suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array for seven items, but then you only put values in the first five. When you loop through all items in the array, the last two are null, so they can't be converted to dates.

Create an array for five items:

```
Dim arr(4) As String
```

Comment: aw yeah..i forgot to change that one..cause before im trying to compute saturday and sunday thats why i use 6